# Imports of system.threading are bugging up

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm trying to use threads to make everything load asynchronous and not make the UI lock up. But now I have a problem, there is not a single error in my code yet I get lots of weird error messages I do not know how to fix, and I can't find the situation I am having on the internet. There is a picture of all the errors below:
[image]

Comment: Is the consuming project referencing a different version of the .NET Framework?

Comment: Does your project target .NET 4.5+?

Comment: @Mark Yes the project targets 4.5+

Comment: @StevenDoggart How do i see this?

Comment: The screenshot cuts off the name in the Project column, but from what I can tell, it looks like there are two projects at play here.  The `ShareLogistics` project is presumably the one which was changed to make use of the new asynchronous stuff.  And the project whose name begins with "ShareLogisticsFMS" is consuming it (i.e., the ShareLogisticsFMS project has a reference to ShareLogistics.exe).  It would seem that the ShareLogistics project compiles fine, but then the consuming project is failing because it doesn't recognize those exposed types.

Comment: So, the problem isn't in ShareLogistics.  That seems to compile without errors.  It's the FMS one that's the problem.  Presumably it's pointing to an different version of the framework which doesn't include those types.

Comment: @StevenDoggart The project column isn't cut off, the name of the project is ShareLogisticsFMS. Do you have any clue on where to fix this problem because I am not at all known to this part of vb.net

Comment: Go to the project properties and find the "Target framework" setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this cracky method, I've instead used Thread Pooling.

```
    'Threading the loading of mutliple parts of 
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf LoadMargins))
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf LoadNonBooking))
```

This starts the functions when there is an open thread available. If there's no available thread it will que till a thread is open.

I've ran into some other problems when i started using this, like cross-thread actions. (I am also using the DevExpress package, but this could help for anything else used in the normal visual basic package.)

Because cross-thread actions are not permitted, we gotta work around this. In this case I wanted to set the source of my GridControl (DevExpress Item) but all the UI stuff is running on the MAIN-thread, not on the thread I just created. So to work my way around this I used this:

```
Private Function LoadMargins()
    Me.SetSource(InvoiceTable)
End Function
```

The SetSource consists of this:

```
Private Sub SetSource(ByVal table As DataTable)
    If Me.GridControl11.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetSourceCallback(AddressOf SetSource)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[table]})
    Else
        Me.GridControl11.DataSource = [table]
    End If
End Sub
```

Invoking something makes the properties of something on the MAIN-thread available to the sub-thread. Somewhere in the top we have a Delegate sub which is for the Callback and being abled to invoke it and then setting the datasource (Some kind of small loop).

```
Delegate Sub SetSourceCallback([table] As DataTable)
```

After I had done this I could edit something in the main thread while using the sub-thread. If I have missed something or if I have been unclear about something, please tell me